# How to split string across new lines and keep blank lines?

Tags: ruby, string, split

Given the ruby code:

```
"aaaa\nbbbb\n\n".split(/\n/)
```

This outputs:

```
["aaaa", "bbbb"]
```

I would like the output to include the blank line indicated by `\n\n` -- I want the result to be:

```
["aaaa", "bbbb", ""]
```

What is the easiest/best way to get this exact result?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I'd recommend using `lines` instead of `split` for this task. `lines` will retain the trailing line-break, which allows you to see the desired empty-line. Use `chomp` to clean up:

```
"aaaa\nbbbb\n\n".lines.map(&:chomp)
[
    [0] "aaaa",
    [1] "bbbb",
    [2] ""
]
```

---

Other, more convoluted, ways of getting there are:

```
"aaaa\nbbbb\n\n".split(/(\n)/).each_slice(2).map{ |ary| ary.join.chomp }
[
    [0] "aaaa",
    [1] "bbbb",
    [2] ""
]
```

It's taking advantage of using a capture-group in `split`, which returns the split text with the intervening text being split upon. `each_slice` then groups the elements into two-element sub-arrays. `map` gets each two-element sub-array, does the `join` followed by the `chomp`.

Or:

```
"aaaa\nbbbb\n\n".split(/(\n)/).delete_if{ |e| e == "\n" }
[
    [0] "aaaa",
    [1] "bbbb",
    [2] ""
]
```

Here's what `split` is returning:

```
"aaaa\nbbbb\n\n".split(/(\n)/)
[
    [0] "aaaa",
    [1] "\n",
    [2] "bbbb",
    [3] "\n",
    [4] "",
    [5] "\n"
]
```

We don't see that used very often, but it can be useful.

Comment: I like this answer.  It strikes me as capturing my intention most clearly.

Comment: Yep, I like this better as well, and avoids the yuck of split's numeric argument.

Comment: @shiva, You can't use `map` on a [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html) in MRI, as it isn't a method. Perhaps you're adding in something that extends String?

Comment: Been a Ruby guy for six years and you just taught me about the `lines` method. Brilliant, thank you.

Answer (score 16):

You can supply a negative argument for the second parameter of split to avoid stripping trailing empty strings;

```
"aaaa\nbbbb\n\n".split(/\n/, -1)
```

Note that this will give you one extra empty string compared to what you want.

Comment: wow, the name of that argument in the docs does NOT make that obvious. thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the numeric argument, but IMO it's a bit tricky since (IMO) it's not quite consistent with what I'd expect, and AFAICT you'd want to trim the last null field:

```
jruby-1.6.7 :020 > "aaaa\nbbbb\n\n".split(/\n/, -1)[0..-2]
 => ["aaaa", "bbbb", ""]
```