# Split string at end of line (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split

I have a hard time converting this string into an array holding each line as an element.

```
string =
"03 54 56 34 34
34 54 56 43 34 56
43 56 67 34 34"
```

I tried `string_array= [string.split(/$/)]`. However, `string_array` then only holds one element (the whole string). What am I missing?

Side note: The individual numbers in the string are seperated by one whitespace, however, each end of a line does not contain a whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string_array = string.split(/\n/)` should do the job.

Comment: This has a problem, that it can leave remainders for line ends in split items. The other solution is better

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062126/how-to-split-string-across-new-lines-and-keep-blank-lines

Answer (score 2):

You could also use method `lines`:

```
string.lines.to_a # => ["03 54 56 34 34\n", "34 54 56 43 34 56\n", "43 56 67 34 34"]
```

And, you could also use `chomp` would like to have the new line characters removed:

```
string.lines.map(&:chomp) # => ["03 54 56 34 34", "34 54 56 43 34 56", "43 56 67 34 34"]
```